# running pgAdmin with docker (windows), persist usersettings over container reboot

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, docker-for-windows

running on windows in this way

```
docker run -d -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="admin@admin.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="root" -p 8000:80 dpage/pgadmin4 -v /c/DockerMountedFolder/PgAdmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
```

i've mounted this host folder `c:/DockerMountedFolder/PgAdmin`  with the container folder `/var/lib/pgadmin`
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#mapped-files-and-directories

nothing is written in `c:/DockerMountedFolder/PgAdmin` nothing is persisted over reboots, no errors in the docker logs

```
2024-02-13 07:05:37 NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
2024-02-13 07:05:37 
2024-02-13 07:05:37 pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
2024-02-13 07:05:37 ======================================
2024-02-13 07:05:37 
2024-02-13 07:06:18 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:18 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:18 +0000] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 2207 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:18 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:18 +0000] "GET /browser/js/endpoints.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 3025 "http://localhost:8000/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:18 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:18 +0000] "GET /tools/translations.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "http://localhost:8000/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:21 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:21 +0000] "POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 205 "http://localhost:8000/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2625 "http://localhost:8000/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/browser.css?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 2788 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/js/endpoints.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 3025 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/js/constants.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 455 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/js/messages.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 757 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /tools/translations.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/server/supported_servers.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /browser/js/utils.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 2194 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:22 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:22 +0000] "GET /user_management/current_user.js?ver=70600 HTTP/1.1" 200 274 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:23 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:23 +0000] "GET /static/css/webcabin.overrides.css?v=1707804383324 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:23 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:23 +0000] "GET /browser/nodes/ HTTP/1.1" 200 255 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:23 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:23 +0000] "GET /browser/check_corrupted_db_file HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:23 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:23 +0000] "GET /misc/bgprocess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:23 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:23 +0000] "POST /browser/master_password HTTP/1.1" 200 174 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:24 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:24 +0000] "POST /settings/store HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:24 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:24 +0000] "GET /preferences/get_all HTTP/1.1" 200 8990 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:24 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:24 +0000] "GET /settings/get_tree_state/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:26 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:26 +0000] "GET /browser/server_group/children/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:54 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:54 +0000] "POST /settings/save_tree_state/ HTTP/1.1" 200 63 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:06:54 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:06:54 +0000] "GET /settings/get_tree_state/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-13 07:05:37 postfix/postlog: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-02-13 07:05:42 [2024-02-13 06:05:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2024-02-13 07:05:42 [2024-02-13 06:05:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
2024-02-13 07:05:42 [2024-02-13 06:05:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2024-02-13 07:05:42 [2024-02-13 06:05:42 +0000] [91] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 91
2024-02-13 07:11:24 ::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024:06:11:24 +0000] "POST /misc/cleanup HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:8000/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

is a silent permission issue? do i need to mount a different folder? other?